# How to resolve container-ip-address in my flutter app using dio package?

Tags: flutter, docker, docker-compose

Everytime i docker-compose up. The app runs fine on 4040. But the api call give me errors when checked in console of web-browser. ERROR - GET http://backend:8888/api/screen net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I am trying to get my backend-container ip-address in place of the api call 'backend':8888. But it takes the same name as i have given in the url below

```
void fetchData() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      var host = 'backend';
      print(host);
      var response = await dio.get(
        "http://backend:8888/api/screen",
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          lineData = jsonDecode(response.data);
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } on DioError catch (err) {
      print(err);
      isLoading = false;
    } catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

My docker-compose-file

```
version: '3'
services:
  playground-web-frontend:
    build:
      context: ./flutterapp
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
  backend:
    image: backend
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
```

I tried giving container-name,service-name. I exec into my flutter app container using bash and then curl onto the api using backend-container ip address. It works and gives me correct data

Error - ERROR - GET http://backend:8888/api/screen net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Answer (score 0):

By adding static ip address in docker-compose.yml file. Please handle cors server-side in flutter web apps.

```
version: '3'
networks:
  fullstack:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
services:
  playground-web-frontend:
    build:
      context: ./flutterapp
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    networks:
      fullstack:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.6
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
  backend:
    image: backend
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    networks:
      fullstack:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.7
```